# Implementing Include? to build Ruby Grocery List

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, include

Brand new to learning Ruby and I'm trying to understand how to use ***.include?*** to build a Grocery List with Ruby.  Specifically my method needs to take 2x arguments with the 1st = item to be added and 2nd = array of the grocery list.  The method needs to add new items to the list and it also needs to recognize if an item is already included in the list.

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  if [list].include?(item) == false
    list << item
  else [list].include?(item) == true
    list
  end
end
```

Here is the TDD that is testing the code:

```
describe "add_item!" do
  it "adds an item to the end of the list" do
    expect( add_item!("banana", ["orange"]) ).to eq(["orange", "banana"])
  end
  it "doesn't add an item if the list already has it" do
    expect( add_item!("orange", ["orange"]) ).to eq(["orange"])
  end
end
```

My code is returning 
    ["orange", "banana"]
on the first test, but
    ["orange", "orange"]
on the second test.

I know this is an easy challenge, but I'm not understanding if I used .include? correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use brackets. If You defined Your array as a variable already then just use its name. For example list = ["oranges", "bananas"]. Ruby already knows list is an array containing those items so when You call a function:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
   unless list.include?(item)
    list << item
   else
    puts "Item already on the list"
   end
  end
```

That way code will look less confusing. "Unless" is similar to "IF" statement but it already checks if the statement is false. In this example it's checking if list includes item already, if yes (true), it skips to "else", if its false (item not in the list) it runs the code, hence adding item to the list.

Overall everything is alright, just get rid of the brackets.

Im also learning Ruby and it is a great language, good luck and do not give up.

Comment: list << item unless list.include?(item)  This is how the solution listed the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine besides the brackets. you shouldnt need those. Also, there is no reason to call list or use the else.

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  if list.include?(item) == false
    list << item
  end
end
```

On further review, why are you trying to pass [orange]? your method defines a list as the value you are looking for. wouldn't you rather pass list?

```
list = []

add_item!("orange", list)
add_item!("bananna", list)
```

Comment: List.include?(item) is checking to see if the item "orange" is already contained in the array [List].  At least this is what I was thinking, but maybe I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you surround an array with square brackets it becomes an array of arrays. Therefore `include?` will return false:

```ruby
[['orange']].include('orange') # => false
```

Here's a hint in order to shorten your code:

```
def add_item(item, list)
  list.include?(item) ? list : list << item
end
```